# Pass text value to another text

Tags: java, android

I want to build a category list scrollview in android studio using java.
I having truble to understand how to pass value from TextView to anthor TextView with same value in other activity.

activity_first.xml

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/PersonName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Name" />
```

FirstActivity.java

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView PersonName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        PersonName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PersonName);

        PersonName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent p = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(p);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In second activity i have a scrollview.

activity_second.xml

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Father" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Mother" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

in activity_second.xml when I press on TextView it will return me with the value Father (id:textView) to the FirstActivity and change the TextView (id:PersonName) to father and if I'll do it with value mother (id:textView2) it will do same action and return me to FirstActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using getExtra method

[Google Android getExtra](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getExtras())

SecondActivity.java

```
    public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mother,father;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second.xml);

        mother = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        father = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);


        mother.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("id", seciliodaid);
                bundle.putInt("type", 0);
                Intent newIntent;
                newIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
                newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
            }
        });

 father.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("id", seciliodaid);
                bundle.putInt("type", 1);
                Intent newIntent;
                newIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
                newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

FirstActivity.java

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView PersonName;
    Bundle data;
    int type=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
     

        PersonName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PersonName);

        try {
                data = getIntent().getExtras();
                type = data.getInt("type");
                if(type==0){
                  PersonName.setText("Mother");
                }else if(type==1){
                  PersonName.setText("Father");
                }
         }catch (Exception e){
         }

        PersonName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent p = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(p);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use `Bundle` to do so (as another answer suggests), if you just need strings, then you can do the following (which I believe is simpler but it would depend on your implementation):

In button `onClickListener` of **FirstActivity.java**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Mother", mother.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("Father", father.getText().toString());
```

In text view `onClickListener` of **SecondActivity.java**:

```
String mother = getIntent().getStringExtra("Mother");
String father = getIntent().getStringExtra("Father");
```